# MySQL query for sales data based per week

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a table with quotes. Each quote has it own status and timestamp. For example:

- status (e.g. "quote_25", "quote_50", "quote_75", "accepted", "cancelled")
- project_id (INT)
- revenue (DECIMAL)
- quote_25_set_on (DATETIME)
- quote_50_set_on (DATETIME)
- quote_75_set_on (DATETIME)
- quote_accepted_set_on (DATETIME)

Now I want to query the data per calender week:

```
SELECT YEARWEEK(quote_25_set_on, 1) calendarweek, SUM(revenue) totalRevenue
FROM quotes
WHERE project_id = "XXXXX"
GROUP BY calendarweek
```

Works as expected. But I need to accumulate the values while they are in a specific status. If a quote is pending for 4 weeks in status 25, I need the revenue value in all 4 calender weeks and not only in the one from the creation timestamp.

How could I solve this?

Comment: How is pending established - is it based on current date? Also I'm not clear on status does status progress from quote_25>>quote_50>>quote_75>>accepted with cancel at any undated point? can any of the status points be skipped?

Comment: @P.Salmon yes exactly. you can always go up, but no go down. but it is also possible to skip 50 and jump from 25 to 100 for example.